# Wrapping Gift Algorithm unpredictably getting things wrong all the time

Tags: algorithm, math, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm working on an assembly x86 school project. During this project, we are asked to generate a set number of points and then apply the wrapping gift algorithm to them. My goal is to put the resulting point's indexes into the "enveloppe" array. The coordinates are generated and stored into coordx and coordy such that a given point at index A has the coordinates of (coordx[A], coordy[A]).

Until that point, the project works fine. But actually applying the algorithm turned out to be much more of a problem than I thought, and so I come to you in this time of need.

The detection of the best candidate for the next point is done through a long calculation of a vectorial product, and I highly suspect the problem comes from that.
The program crashes about 75% of the time as it keeps looping and adding more and more entries into "enveloppe", never coming back to the original point. There are however a few times when it stops correctly as it finds itself coming back to the original point; But the enveloppe is still very wrong even in these cases.
I have to mention most of the times I've tried looking at the convex hull it actually generated, even drawing a graph to see what it would look like, there seems to be no logic, at least to me. It's completely random.

```
extern printf

global main

%DEFINE NUM_POINTS 20
%DEFINE MAX_X 255
%DEFINE MAX_Y 255

section .data

section .bss
coordx: resw NUM_POINTS
coordy: resw NUM_POINTS
enveloppe: resw NUM_POINTS
sizeEnveloppe: resb 1
randnum: resw 1
minpoint: resw 1

section .text
main:
; Génération des points du programme
mov rbx, 0
populatex:
    rdrand ax
    mov [randnum], ax
    modx:
        sub word[randnum], MAX_X
        cmp word[randnum], MAX_X
        jae modx
    mov ax, word[randnum]
    mov word[coordx+rbx*2], ax
    
    inc rbx
    cmp rbx, NUM_POINTS
    jb populatex

mov rbx, 0
populatey:
    rdrand ax
    mov word[randnum], ax
    mody:
        sub word[randnum], MAX_Y
        cmp word[randnum], MAX_Y
        jae mody
    mov ax, word[randnum]
    mov word[coordy+rbx*2], ax

    inc rbx
    cmp rbx, NUM_POINTS
    jb populatey
    
; Trouver le point le plus à gauche
mov rbx, 0
mov word[minpoint], bx
inc rbx
minAlgo:
    ; On récupère le point minimum actuel
    movzx rcx, word[minpoint]
    movzx rax, word[coordx+rcx*2]
    
    ; On le compare au point parcouru actuel
    cmp ax, word[coordx+rbx*2]
    jb lower
            
    ; Si minpoint > point actuel, on mets point actuel dans minpoint
    mov rax, rbx
    mov word[minpoint], ax

    lower:
    inc rbx
    cmp rbx, NUM_POINTS
    jb minAlgo

; Une fois cette étape fini, nous connaissons le point le plus à gauche.
; Marche de Jarvis
; rax = Prochain point (P)
; rbx = Index actuel de enveloppe (Pas d'équivalent, à ne pas utiliser pr l'instant)
; rcx = Prochain candidat de P (Q)
movzx rax, word[minpoint]
mov rbx, 0
mov rcx, 0
jarvis:
    ; On mets le dernier resultat dans enveloppe
    mov word[enveloppe+rbx*2], ax
        
        push rax
        mov rdi, fmt_printf
        mov si, word[enveloppe+rbx*2]
        mov rax, 0
        call printf
        pop rax

    movzx rcx, ax
    
    push rbx
    ; rbx devient (I)
    mov rbx, 0
    parcoursPoints:

        ; Calcul du produit vectoriel
        ; r8w = xP
        mov r8w, word[coordx+rax*2]
        ; r9w = yP
        mov r9w, word[coordy+rax*2]
        ; r10w = xI
        mov r10w, word[coordx+rbx*2]
        ; r11w = yI
        mov r11w, word[coordy+rbx*2]
        ; r10 = r10 - r8 = xPI
        sub r10w, r8w
        ; r11 = r11 - r9 = yPI
        sub r11w, r9w
        ; r8w = xI
        mov r8w, word[coordx+rbx*2]
        ; r9w = yI
        mov r9w, word[coordy+rbx*2]
        ; r12 = xQ
        mov r12w, word[coordx+rcx*2]
        ; r13 = yQ
        mov r13w, word[coordy+rcx*2]
        ; r12 = r12 - r8 = xIQ
        sub r12w, r8w
        ; r13 = r13 - r9 = yIQ
        sub r13w, r9w
        ; xIQ * yPI = r12 * r11
        imul r12w, r11w
        ; xPI * yIQ = r10 * r13
        imul r10w, r13w
        ; Produit vectoriel => r12
        sub r12w, r10w
        cmp r12w, 0
        jl notcandidate
        
        mov rcx, rbx
        
        notcandidate:
        inc rbx
        
        cmp rbx, NUM_POINTS
        jb parcoursPoints
    ; rbx redevient l'index actuel de l'enveloppe)
    pop rbx
    inc rbx
    mov rax, rcx    
    
    cmp ax, word[enveloppe]
    jne jarvis

; Pour fermer le programme proprement :
mov    rax, 60         
mov    rdi, 0
syscall

ret
```

I know this is quite a big chunk of code but I need to understand where I went wrong... I can't even truly understand the results of my program, they seem almost random.

Please and thank you in advance for any answer.

I tried switching around a few of the variables in the calculation of the vectorial product, which ultimately didn't work and gave barely different results.

I also tried to print a LOT of variables to understand some sort of pattern in how it gets things wrong, but again, it's seemingly completely random.

Comment: What I used to do for assembly assignments was: 1. write out a solution in a higher level language (that you're more comfortable with) and test, then 2. convert to assembly and test. That way, there's one of two outcomes: if it fails in the first step, the issue is with algorithm; if in the second step, then something went wrong with the conversion to assembly. You should also save a few of your testcases (the ones that crash and the ones that give wrong input) so that you can test your implementation in the first step does against those.

Comment: It would help if you described the algorithm and the formula. Also the terminating condition maybe safer by just `cmp rbx, NUM_POINTS` so you do not write more points than what you have which probably means you used the same point multiple times. Maybe your inner loop should not start from zero but hard to tell without the algo.

Comment: Also you should use (and post) fixed test data and not random, until you get it right.